# Placing <textarea> inside tinymce (yes this again)

Tags: html, forms, tinymce, textarea

I've searched and searched for 2 days and I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

So, in my CMS the normal operation for loading and saving content into TinyMCE works fine, but all goes to Lucifer's world when I add textarea for a contact form or anything for that matter. Code goes as follows:

GET POSTED DATA TO SAVE:

```
//get page info

$pnfo = $dbase->getPage("page_a_link", $page2edit);

if($_POST['pageedit']!='') { 

    //to be success message
    $sHeader = '<span style="text-align: center;"><h3><span style="color:green;">'
    .ucfirst($page2edit).' has Been Succesfully Updated</span></h3></span>'; 

    //content to be injected into page
        $sContent = "<? ";

        // add access level
        if ( $pnfo['page_level'] !== GUEST_LEVEL ) {
            if ( $pnfo['page_level'] == MEMBER_LEVEL ) {
                $sContent .="  \$access_level='members';";
            } else {
                $sContent .="  \$access_level=".$pnfo['page_level'].";";        
            }
            $sContent .="  include('../inc/pageauth.inc.php'); ";       
        } 

        $sContent .=" ?> ";

        //add posted content
        $sContent .= stripslashes($_POST['pageedit']);

        // inject   article module  
        if ( $pnfo['isblog'] == "1" ) {
            $sContent .="<? \$page='".$pnfo['page_bread']."'; include('../inc/modules.inc/articles.mod/inject.articles.mod.php'); ?>";
        } 

    //add content to page
    file_put_contents("../../../content/page/tpl/".$page2edit,$sContent);

    // echo success message
    echo $sHeader;
}
```

---

AND THE CODE FOR RENDERING IT IN TINYMCE

---

```
$render_pages .= '<textarea id="pageedit" name="pageedit" style="width:900px;height:800px;display:block;">';   
  ob_start();
  error_reporting(0); 
  include('../../../content/page/tpl/'.$page2edit);
  $render_pages .= ob_get_clean();
$render_pages .= '</textarea>';
```

---

AND A IMPORTANT PART TO DISPLAY AS WELL (YOU'LL READ WHY INA MIN)
MY SUBMIT BUTTON:

---

```
$render_pages .= '<input type="image" onclick="javascript: window.open(\'pages\',\'_self\')"';
```

---

KEEP IN MIND, EVERYTHING WORKS PERFECT WITHOUT ADDING A `<TEXTAREA>`

Alright, so when i add a textarea what happens is when it saves, it says it saves but not the page itself, but "pages", which is what I'm posting to (my submit button).

I understand how a textarea should be rendered and here's all the solutions I tried that failed:

---

1:

```
$render_pages .= '<textarea id="pageedit" name="pageedit" style="width:900px;height:800px;display:block;">';   
  ob_start();
  error_reporting(0); 
  $src = include '../../../content/page/tpl/'.$page2edit;
  $render_pages .= htmlspecialchars($src); (also with ENT_NOQUOTES)
  $render_pages .= ob_get_clean();
$render_pages .= '</textarea>';
```

2:

```
$render_pages .= '<textarea id="pageedit" name="pageedit" style="width:900px;height:800px;display:block;">';   
  ob_start();
  error_reporting(0); 
  htmlspecialchars(include('../../../content/page/tpl/'.$page2edit));
  $render_pages .= ob_get_clean();
$render_pages .= '</textarea>';
```

3:

```
$sContent .= stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pageedit']));
```

4:

```
$file = file_get_contents('../../../content/page/tpl/'.$page2edit, true);
$file = str_replace('</textarea>', htmlspecialchars('</textarea>'), $file);
$render_pages .= '<textarea id="pageedit" name="pageedit" style="width:900px;height:800px;display:block;">';   
  $render_pages .= $file;
$render_pages .= '</textarea>';
```

5:

```
$file = file_get_contents('../../../content/page/tpl/'.$page2edit, true);
$file = str_replace('</textarea>', htmlspecialchars('</textarea>'), $file);
$render_pages .= '<textarea id="pageedit" name="pageedit" style="width:900px;height:800px;display:block;">';   
  ob_start();
  $render_pages .= $file;
  $render_pages .= ob_get_clean();
$render_pages .= '</textarea>';
```

---

(and I tried htmlentities in all solutions as well)

Nothing works, all solutions breaks the page 1 or 2 ways:

---

1.

breaks at echoing the success header, but with "pages" as the page name instead of the actual page name to be saved (remember, "pages" is the link im posting to in my image submit button - which calls a simple java code to submit the form - im sure most of you figured that) and it stops the rest of the page from showing

2.

same as the first, but it doesent break the rest of the page.

---

-.- I'm so confused by this. >.<

Help, perhaps? o.O

PS: I tried to format this post right, keep messing up I think though.

Comment: thanks thirty for editing for me

Answer (score 1):

Yeeeeeea, so i just needed to 'reset' the content,  as in, clear the page. load it into tinymce as a blank page, THEN added the textarea tag with solution 3 already in place and all is well. ^.^

short an sweet, i had to convert the textarea file before rendering it in tinymce THEN convert it back right before save (seems like a huge duh now) and now the infinite beautiful loop of saving and editing textarea's iny TinyMCE is well.